# Toshiba won't install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, toshiba-satellite

Toshiba Satellite laptop with Windows 8, I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.

I set the Boot mode to CSM boot, turning off secure boot.

The computer boots up on my USB stick to the Ununtu menu, but when I select install or try live the screen goes blank and that's it.

I've tried several times.

So far not a fan of UEFI ;-P

Thanks in advance
Jake

Comment: how much have you waited ?

Comment: what model is it? since it boots up to the menu, I don't think it is an UEFI issue.
this could be a new hardware/missing driver issue. probably dual graphic card.

Comment: You should intall in UEFI mode, not CSM mode in order to boot both Windows and Ubuntu.